# Assert function returns original type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to assert that a function returns a value that has type of the value given as an argument to the function, yet keep the wider argument type restrictions than of the original value?

**Example:**
I want to trim a string value, but if the value is `null` or `undefined`, I want it to return the original `null` or `undefined`.

```
function trimOrOriginal(value?: string | null) {
    return value ? value.trim() : value;
};
```

Let's say I have non-optional field of type `string | null`. If I want to trim this field and assign the trimmed value to the original variable, I get a compiler error because the `trimOrOriginal` can return `undefined` even though I know it can never be `undefined` as the value I gave for the parameter is never `undefined`.

I could use generics:

```
const trimOrOriginal = <T>(value: T) => {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        return value.trim();
    }
    return value;
};
```

But this doesn't look nice. I would like to specify that the argument type has to be "string".

Comment: `T extends string | null`

Comment: "Doesn't look nice" is subjective; do you have some objective criteria we can use to determine what answer might work? If you really have the restriction that you can't use generics, then the only other possibility is [overloads](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), which some say is less "nice" than generics. What's the use case?  How would you like to call `trimOrOriginal()`? Should it accept `trimOrOriginal(Math.random()<0.5? " abc " : null)`? If so, what type should be output? `string | null`? `"abc" | null`? Something else? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to infer the return type based on the argument type.

```
const example1 = trimOrOriginal(null) // inferred type null
const example2 = trimOrOriginal("bla") // inferred type string
let input: string | undefined = "blub"
const example3 = trimOrOriginal(input) // inferred type string | undefined
```

For this you need to use generic types and type constraints.
There is no way to do this without generics. That said, an implementation could look like this:

```
const trimOrOriginal = <T extends string | null | undefined >(s: T) =>
  (typeof s === 'string' ? s.trim() : s) as T extends string ? string : T
```

The conditional return type is necessary to widen string literals to strings:

```
type SL = "a " | "b " // constructed example
const a: SL = "a "
const example4 = trimOrOriginal(a) // inferred type is now string, not SL!
const sl: SL = trimOrOriginal(a) // type error, string is not assignable to SL
```

In real life, just use `s?.trim()` :-)

Comment: You might want the return type to be `as T extends string ? string : T` so that the output type isn't incorrectly assumed to be the same string literal as the input.